# Grafana dashboard custom variable as a json object

Tags: grafana, graphite

We are using grafana to visualize our metrics and very glad to use it.

For one dashboard I need to create custom variable to show host name. For example, we have the first variable: `host` with query `collectd.localhost.ping.ping-*` and regexp `/ping-(.*)/`. It returns a list of hosts that we ping. Now I want to add showing title depends on selected host. I think need to add another custom variable `title` like map `host1:Title1;host2:Title2` and in the panel's title write something like `Proxy ${title:json}.${host}` in result get **Proxy TitleN**.

How to do it? We use 7.2.1 grafana version.
Thank you!

Comment: I got very excited when I saw this page existed, and less so when I saw there was no answer.  Bummer!  Really surprised no one has an answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a great answer, but given it's been nearly two years without *any* answer, I'll proffer it.  Having just commented how I was surprised no one had in fact answered, I kept poking around.  Eventually I found that if added a variable interactively, and then I clicked *dashboard settings* followed by *JSON Model* I got to a description that included new data in the *templating* field.  I pasted that into my original JSON description of the dashboard, and restarted Grafana --- the change persisted.